# avoiding creating a new object with linq

Tags: c#, linq

i am not very familiar with linq syntax, and i am not sure if this query is the perfect fit of what i am trying to achieve but its working perfectly.
how can i make it better and is it possible avoiding the use of a new tuple or a new object?

```
byte[] ShuffledBytes= new byte[20];
byte[] Indecies = new byte[20]; //holds the right index for each byte in Bytes

    var orderdBytes = 
                    Indecies.
                    Zip(ShuffledBytes, (i, b) => new Tuple<byte,byte>(b,i)).
                    OrderBy(o => o.Item2).
                    Select(o => o.Item1).
                    ToArray();
```

Comment: If you do not want to transform your result into a list of some kind of objects, what do you expect the linq statement to do?

Comment: @MichaC its just that i am creating an object just for ordering, and in the end result i just want a byte[], also was wondering if anyone would do it the same way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think want you want is `Array.Sort` rather than LINQ.  One of the overloads uses one array as the key and the other as the items to sort:

```
Array.Sort(Indecies, ShuffledBytes);
```

No extra objects needed ShuffledBytes is sorted according to the values in Indecies.

Another option would be to use a sorted dictionary or a list of keyvaluepair's, rather than 2 arrays.

Comment: woah thats just perfect!